# 4 unicode chars appear as first few characters in file which don't seem to show in vim

Tags: mysql, charset

`vi data.sql` :

```
-- MariaDB dump 10.19  Distrib 10.4.28-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
```

But when I do `head -n 10 data.sql` I get the first line as

```
��-- MariaDB dump 10.19  Distrib 10.4.28-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
```

As a result of which I get this while importing :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '??-' at line 1
```

So how do I rectify this ?

Comment: Those are probably a BOM (byte order mark), I don't use MySQL so don't know if there's an option to ignore it but you could do a search on how to remove that from the SQL file.

Comment: How you were generating this file? Were you editing it with e.g. Notepad (which adds BOM)?

Comment: I used a Windows 11 version of mysqldump to dump the 1.5GB SQL and was trying to import it in a Ubuntu 22.04 server.

Answer (score 1):

Get the hex of the beginning of the file; see https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#bom_byte_order_mark for what BOM looks like.  Otherwise, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for "black diamond".

If it is BOM, try to get the product that is generating it to stop, somehow remove the first 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved by opening the sql file in vi and

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:wq
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a BOM or other garbage added by your editor, you can mask it in the file  it using the command

```
echo -n --xx | dd conv=notrunc of=data.sql
```

This just overwrites the bytes with an SQL comment, which Mysql (or Mariadb) will ignore.